# How to return two fields, with different limits on posts in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, collections, meteor, find

I have a collection called Posts I am trying output the {{url}} but limit it to only the first one and trying to output the {{thumbs}} but all of them. So far the only thing that is happening is all the {{thumbs}} are showing, because it comes last, how do I get theme both to work?

```
return Posts.find({}, {fields: { url: 1}, limit:1}), Posts.find({}, {fields: { thumb: 1}});
```

**EDIT**
The template helper in whole

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({
  posts: function() {

    Posts.find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1}}).map(function(post, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    return post;
  } else {
    delete post.thumb;
    return post;
  }
});
}
});
```

Comment: Is this inside of a publish function or a template helper?

Comment: @davidWeldon this is inside a template helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Posts.find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1}}).map(function(post, index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    return post;
  } else {
    delete post.thumb;
    return post;
  }
});
```

It finds all Posts with both fields, and removes the thumb only if the post isn't the first one.

Comment: Right now that is returning nothing at all.

Comment: I just created a test app and the code worked for me. Maybe some unrelated thing is preventing them from appearing.

Comment: could it possibly be because of the post function the query is wrapped in. I added the whole template helper above.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code. It looks like you just left off the `return` before `Posts.find`.

Comment: Amazing, this seems like a very useful request technique. Exactly what I needed.